# How to check the first item that was checked in a checkbox in asp.net mvc C#

Tags: c#

I wanted to know what is the first item that was checked on a checkbox,

Here is my code to know what are the selected item, but I do not know how to know the first item that was checked.

```
 private List<VehicleOptionalEquipment> SelectedEngineOptions(long vehicleId, int? styleId, List<VehicleOptionalEquipment> optionalEquips)
        {
            var optionEngine = new List<VehicleOptionalEquipment>();

            foreach (var optionalEquip in optionalEquips)
            {
                if (optionalEquip.TypeId == (int)OptionSectionEnum.ENGINE)
                {
                    if (optionalEquip.IsSelected == true)
                    {
                        var engineSelected = new VehicleOptionalEquipment
                        {
                            TypeId = optionalEquip.TypeId,
                            Index = optionalEquip.Index,
                            IsSelected = optionalEquip.IsSelected
                        };
                        optionEngine.Add(engineSelected);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var engineNotSelected = new VehicleOptionalEquipment
                        {
                            TypeId = optionalEquip.TypeId,
                            Index = optionalEquip.Index,
                            IsSelected = optionalEquip.IsSelected
                        };
                        optionEngine.Remove(engineNotSelected);
                    }
                }
            }
            return optionEngine;
        }

    }
```

Here is my model:

```
  public class VehicleOptionalEquipment
    {
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You can't find it here. You need to catch the first item that was checked and send as a another parameter. And also, you can use LINQ query instead of this foreach loop and if conditions.

Comment: If you need to check which item was checked first by the user on the UI then you need to do that on the UI.Either you can pass parameters as mentioned in the comment or you can use some other variable for that.

Comment: @sriharsha yes, I dont have that code above.. the above code only returns the selected item, but not the first item that was checked.. How can I do to catch that? I'm new in these language. Thank you

Comment: If first selected value is unchecked again by the user, then what result you need ?

Comment: @sriharsha by the default all the values are false, so when the user checked the first selected value it will return the value as true, and when the first item was unchecked it will return the value as false..

Comment: Can you try like this link : https://jsfiddle.net/3oznqqLf/1/ -  It will give the order of selected checkbox values in jquery. In that you take first value and pass it as a parameter to this method.

Comment: @sriharsha yes. It is working and it is what I am looking for..
but i am not familiar with jquery, can you do it in a csharp code. :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `foreach` loop and if conditions, you can achieve it in LINQ

```
var optionEngine = optionalEquips.Where(x => x.TypeId == (int)OptionSectionEnum.ENGINE && 
                                                x.IsSelected).ToList();
```

You can get the `engine type` and `IsSelected true` records to the `optionEngine`.